# Setting variable in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I want to set a variable in awk that in composed of appending three strings
containing the filename.  The command is supposed to print lines between numbers `a` and `b`.

```
  find "$dir" \( -name \*.org -o -name \*.texi \)  \
    -exec awk -v a="$na" -v b="$nb"                \
              -v red="$(tput setaf 1)"             \
              -v nrm="$(tput sgr0)"                \
              -v rd="\033[1;31m"                   \
              -v nr="\033[0m"                      \
           's = "==>" FILENAME "<=="
            FNR == 1 {f = 0}
            FNR == a {print red, s, nrm; f = 1}
            f {print; if (FNR == b) nextfile}' {} +
```

Comment: not sure what the question is, but `s = "==>" FILENAME "<=="` will evaluate to true and print line.

Answer (score 1):

You have `s = ...` in the condition part of awk's `condition {action}` syntax. It looks like it should be moved into the `FNR == 1 { ... }` actions:

```
  find "$dir" \( -name \*.org -o -name \*.texi \)  \
    -exec awk -v a="$na" -v b="$nb"                \
              -v red="$(tput setaf 1)"             \
              -v nrm="$(tput sgr0)"                \
           '
            FNR == 1 {s = "==>" FILENAME "<=="; f = 0}
            FNR == a {print red, s, nrm; f = 1}
            f {print; if (FNR == b) nextfile}' {} +
```

Comment: I can also see that it would belong to the `FNR == 1` block.  But I could set `s` another place and just print it when `FNR == a`.  If `s = ...` is a condition, how can I change it to be an assignment to a variable?

Comment: Have inserted `s` as follows  `FNR == 1 {s="\n==> "FILENAME" <==\n"; f = 0}`.  The printing seems as expected this time.

Comment: s=... is an assignment, it's just that you had it outside of `{}` (where it meant "if this expression is true, print the current record").

Comment: I can confirm, because I was getting the output repeated.